# Lambda match on partial object

Tags: c#, lambda, dapper

I am using dapper and a lambda expression in order to retrieve data from the database.  Instead of building a ton of overloaded expressions, i want to pass in a single database object and have my lambda expression match on the closest or first object found.

```
public static User GetUser(User pUser)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
    {
        return connection.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM dbo.USERS").(m => m == pUser);
    }
}
```

In the example above, you can see I am passing a "User" object into the function, this user object could be 50% of what the exepected object is. for example, if the object had 2 strings, the ID and the users name. But I only knew the users name. I would create a new user as an ref or out param and have the query fill in the missing data.

Thoughts?  I could create a ton over overloaded functions with duplated code like GetUserByID, and GetUserByName but that seems redundant.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem, could you clarify why you would like to do it this way, and not, as an example, by using a more ORM-like approach with expressions?

Comment: You're code seems incomplete at `.(m => m == pUser)`.  If that was meant to be a `Where` then this is a horrible idea as you'll pull the entire table.  The idea of dapper is to use straight up SQL so if you go that route then yes you need specific methods for each case with  the specific SQL to match passing in the needed filter values as parameters.

Comment: If you have only the `Name` and not the `Id` it's possible that you find more than one match in the database. What you want to return then? _"I could create a multiple functions with like GetUserByID and GetUserByName but that seems redundant"_  That would be very clear and imo a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-write the query. Kindly provide the structure of dbo.Users table.

Place filter logic inside of query and use table columns to match records instead of whole object.

```
public static User GetUser(User pUser)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            return connection.Query<User>("Select * FROM dbo.Users where userID = @UserId", pUser).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use answers for comments.  If you don't have the rep to comment then be patient until you do.

Comment: Using format to create a SQL query is a bad idea.  Dapper actually handles parameters for you with one of it's overload and would be a better solution. Also `Query` returns a List so you have to pull out a single result.  Something like `return connection.Query<User>("Select * FROM dbo.Users where userID = @UserId", pUser).Single();`